# Cannot send email with Amazon SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using the AWS PHP SDK.  I have the following code to send an email using SES:

```
$ses = new AmazonSES(...);
$response =  $ses->send_email('ubuntu@localhost', 
            array('ToAddresses' => 'myemail@somedomain.com'), 
            array( 
                'Subject.Data' => 'My Test message',
                'Body.Text.Data' => 'my message'
            )
        );
```

Simple enough, right?  But I get the following error from the AWS SDK itself:

```
Undefined index: body

sdk.class.php(828)

// Normalize JSON input
828         if ($query['body'] === '[]')
829         {
830             $query['body'] = '';
831         }
```

My AWS access and secret keys are correct, since I am able to use S3.  What am I missing here?

EDIT:
I verified a different email address on @gmail.com, and used that as the from address instead. I still ran into the original bug reported. I had no problem using the third party library I mentioned though.

Comment: While you should get a real error, have you validated *both* the To and From addresses for sending?  You'll need to do that while you're in the dev sandbox.  Also, SES is super-new, and I think they pushed a new copy of the SDK last week, so that's worth checking...

Comment: How do I validate the email address?  I added a call for $ses->verify_email_address, but nothing changed.  ubuntu@localhost is a user I have running on a local ubuntu instance.

Comment: It has to be a publicly-accessible email address that SES can send to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE: This bug is now patched!  Please download the latest version.**

This seems to be a confirmed bug in the Amazon SDK.  See link below...

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=231411

As far as I can tell, there is no patch for this yet.  I suppose you could patch it yourself using isset().  That's what I did, and it seems to work now.  Again, this is a bug in sdk.class.php on line 828.  I don't feel like making a patch file right now.  Here's what I did to the code, though...

```
// Normalize JSON input
if (!isset($query['body']) || $query['body'] === '[]')
{
    $query['body'] = '';
}
```

Again, not an official patch, but it lets you go on your happy way.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you need a non-private email address which `ubuntu@localhost` clearly isn't.

(edit)  Also from the documentation you need to verify that you are the owner of said email address, which you clearly cannot do with `ubuntu@localhost`.

> **Email Address Verification**
>
> Before you can send your first
>   message, Amazon SES requires that you
>   verify your email address. This is to
>   confirm that you own the email
>   address, and to prevent others from
>   using it.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/es/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?InitialSetup.EmailVerification.html

Comment: Yes, I did add the verify email call with an external email address.  The problem still persisted, and I never received the verification email.

Comment: @Simian because if you tried to verify `ubuntu@localhost` that `localhost` will be Amazon's SES server address and your account is not there.

Comment: No, I meant I verified a different email address on @gmail.com, and used that as the from address instead.  I still ran into the original bug reported.  I had no problem using the third party library I mentioned though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it without the SDK:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

// AMAZON PARAMETERS
$sAccess = 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE';
$sSecret = 'YOUR-SECRET-KEY-GOES-HERE';
$sURL = 'https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'; // may be subject to change!
$nVerifyHost = 1; // may need to set either of these to 0 on some hosting plans
$nVerifyPeer = 1;

// OUR TEST MESSAGE
$sTo = 'you@example.com'; // must request production mode in AWS SES Console
$sFrom = 'sender@example.com'; // must verify the sender in the AWS SES Console
$sSubject = 'Hello, World!';
$sMessage = <<<EOD
<p>This is para 1.</p>

<p>This is para 2.</p>

<p>Regards,<br>
<b>Management</b></p>
EOD;

// SEND THE MESSAGE
$sDate = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s e');
$sSig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sDate, $sSecret, TRUE));
$asHeaders = array();
$asHeaders[] = 'Date: ' .  $sDate;
$asHeaders[] = 'X-Amzn-Authorization: AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=' . $sAccess . 
  ',Algorithm=HmacSHA256,Signature=' . $sSig;
$asHeaders[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$sText = $sMessage;
$sText = str_replace("\r\n",'',$sText);
$sText = str_replace("\r",'',$sText);
$sText = str_replace("\n",'',$sText);
$sText = str_replace("\t",'  ',$sText);
$sText = str_replace('<BR />','<br />',$sText);
$sText = str_replace('<BR/>','<br />',$sText);
$sText = str_replace('<BR>','<br />',$sText);
$sText = str_replace('</P>','</p>',$sText);
$sText = str_replace('</p>',"</p>\n\n",$sText);
$sText = str_replace('<br />',"<br />\n",$sText);
$sText = strip_tags($sText);
$asQuery = array(
  'Action' => 'SendEmail',
  'Destination.ToAddresses.member.1' => $sTo,
  'Source' => $sFrom,
  'Message.Subject.Data' => $sSubject,
  'Message.Body.Text.Data' => $sText,
  'Message.Body.Html.Data' => $sMessage
);
$sQuery = http_build_query($asQuery);

$hCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, $nVerifyHost);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $nVerifyPeer);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sQuery);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $asHeaders);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $sURL);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$asResult = array('code'=>'','error'=>'');
if (curl_exec($hCurl)) {
  $asResult['code'] = curl_getinfo($hCurl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
} else {
  $asResult['error'] = array (
    'code' => curl_errno($hCurl),
    'message' => curl_error($hCurl),
  );
}
@curl_close($hCurl);
print_r($asResult);
```

Comment: How can I send mass mail using your logic?

Comment: @cawecoy It might be easier to use Mailgun to do mass mails.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in the Amazon SDK.  This wouldn't be the first time.

I've instead opted to use an excellent third party library:

https://github.com/kierangraham/php-ses

And its documentation:
http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/

Works like a charm.

Comment: Found this SDK to be very slow and creates FastCGI timeouts. I'm trying to send about 500 emails at a time, but timesout between 30 and 40. Have requested help with this...

Comment: @andrebruton Your timeouts are probably because of sending limits and/or PHP page time limits. You may not be able to send more than 5 emails a second. You should consider adding the usleep() command like every 5th email. As well, use set_time_limit() in PHP, but some hosting plans block how long you can extend this -- you may need a more flexible hosting plan. Last, consider a queue table and a cron to send mail.